# Create NA tables counts for all columns in a data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
df1 <-
  data.frame(
    letters = sample(
      x = c(letters,NA), replace = T, size = 100
    ),
    LETTERS = sample(
      x = c(LETTERS,NA), replace = T, size = 100
    ),
    Numbers = sample(
      x = c(0:9,NA), replace = T, size = 100
    )
  )
```

I want to generate a data frame with the NA count for every column:

```
data.frame(NA.letters=sum(is.na(df1$letters)),
           NA.LETTERS=sum(is.na(df1$LETTERS)),
           NA.Numbers=sum(is.na(df1$Numbers)))
```

Is there a better way of doing this? My solution is very unpractical when you have many columns. I am thinking of something like `dplyr::rowwise()` but for columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use colSums:

```
colSums(is.na(df1))

letters LETTERS Numbers 
      0       4      10
```